# Issues With OpenBSD VPS

Tags: unix, openbsd

So I wanted to brush up on my Unix/Linux skills, so I obtained a free NetBSD Unix shell account on sdf.org, and also I obtained a OpenBSD VPS with them as well after getting after getting MetaArpa membership with SDF, because I wanted to learn OpenBSD as well.

I was able to successfully install my OpenBSD VPS from the menu provided by SDF on their server at vps3.sdf.org, but when I try to connect to it, I get the error message "openbsd does not support PV style console". A google search of this issue found nothing. I tried connecting to vps3.sdf.org using Putty, and had this same message, I connected also with ssh from my SDF NetBSD shell account, also the same error, I also connected to the server using OpenSSH from the command line on my Windows 10 laptop, same error, also tried to connect using a VNC client, not able to connect using VNC client.

I tried contacting someone on the OpenBSD IRC on Freenode, a person there did a grep on /usr/bin on his own OpenBSD and found no "PV" error messages, so that person is saying the issue is most likely on the SDF side. I also sent emails to SDF admins, no replies yet.

The IP address 205.166.94.88 is not reachable.

Here is a screenshot of the error I get:

[image: OpenBSD VPS Issue]

Comment: I guess that "PV" stands for paravirtualization, which is something that in xen lingo means a virtualization which is neither userland emulation, nor hardware virtualization (eg. kvm), but something where an OS is especially modified to run on top of xen. Translated, that should probably mean that they don't support OpenBSD as a Xen guest. Sorry if this is not accurate, I've lost all my interest in this stuff since amd-v/kvm works so well ;-)

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I have not worked with virtualization too much before so I am not too familiar with the different types, but looking into it now, I am just waiting for some of my laptops to be repaired and when I get them back, I am going to install OpenBSD on one of them, but I was really hoping to work with it in in this new VPS I have in the meantime.

Comment: Ok thanks to a suggestion from a person on IRC, I found out another place where an OpenBSD account can be had for free, https://tilde.institute, looking into it, applied for an account with them today.

Comment: Ok so before I tried to setup this OpenBSD VPS, I applied to have a KVM OpenBSD VPS with hostsailor.com, which seemed like a great deal for $2.99 per month, I sent them a payment and they sent me an email saying my VPS was configured, but I was never able to connect to it with the IP they gave me, I asked them if they had a different IP I could use, and they never got back to me about it. I am just not having much luck trying to get an OpenBSD VPS.

Comment: [Vultr](https://www.vultr.com/) provide support for OpenBSD VPS.